# Regular Expression Validator behaving weirdly

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-ajax

I have a web application which allow user to send report with up to 5 jpg images. Somehow I manage to let user sent report with up to 5 jpg images. But something weird happen after submitting the report with some jpg images, the regular expression validator of fileupload (the fileupload which the user previously inserted with jpg image) prompt the error message of "Only jpg files are allowed", I not sure what went wrong in my code. Do help me take a look on my code below. Thanks!

Aspx Page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script language = "Javascript">
function tbLimit() {
    var tbObj = event.srcElement;
    if (tbObj.value.length == tbObj.maxLength * 1) return false;
}
function tbCount(visCnt) {
    var tbObj = event.srcElement;
    if (tbObj.value.length > tbObj.maxLength * 1) tbObj.value = tbObj.value.substring(0, tbObj.maxLength * 1);
    if (visCnt) visCnt.innerText = tbObj.maxLength - tbObj.value.length;
}
</script>

<div id="headerbody">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="btnCancel"
    ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to cancel this report?"
    Enabled="true"/>

<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender2" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="btnReport"
    ConfirmText="False report may lead to disciplinary action!"
    Enabled="true"/>

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <h2 align="center">Report</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="auto-style1" align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Type of Crimes:"></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </th>
        <td align ="left">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTOC" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25px" Width="150px">
            <asp:ListItem>Theft</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Loan Shark</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Robbery</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Gang</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Vandalism</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Accident</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="auto-style1" align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </th>
        <td align ="left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25px" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLocation" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter the crime location." 
            ControlToValidate="txtLocation" Display="None">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="rfvLocation" >
            </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="auto-style1" align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Date & Time:"></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </th>
        <td align ="left">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="auto-style1" align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Detail:"></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </th>
        <td align ="left">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDetail" runat="server" Height="75px" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" style="margin-left: 25px"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDetail" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter detail of the crime." 
            ControlToValidate="txtDetail" Display="None">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender2" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="rfvDetail" >
            </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>

            <br />
            You have <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" Text="500"></asp:Label> &nbsp;characters left.
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="auto-style1" align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Picture:"></asp:Label>
            <br /> 
        </th>
        <td align ="left">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25px"/>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"   
            ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" Runat="Server" ErrorMessage="Only jpg files are allowed"   
            ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG)$"/>
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25px" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2"   
            ControlToValidate="FileUpload2" Runat="Server" ErrorMessage="Only jpg files are allowed"   
            ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG)$"/>
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload3" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25px" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3"   
            ControlToValidate="FileUpload3" Runat="Server" ErrorMessage="Only jpg files are allowed"   
            ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG)$"/>
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload4" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25px" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4"   
            ControlToValidate="FileUpload4" Runat="Server" ErrorMessage="Only jpg files are allowed"   
            ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG)$"/>
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload5" runat="server" style="margin-left: 25px" Height="22px" Width="217px" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5"   
            ControlToValidate="FileUpload5" Runat="Server" ErrorMessage="Only jpg files are allowed"   
            ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG)$"/>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Button ID="btnReport" runat="server" Text="Report" OnClick="btnReport_Click" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
        <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="head">
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 469px;
    }
</style>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            String username = (String)Session["username"];
            String datetime = (String)Session["datetime"];
            String typeofcrime = ddlTOC.SelectedItem.Text;
            String location = txtLocation.Text;
            String detail = txtDetail.Text;

            // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
            string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

            string filePath2 = FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename2 = Path.GetFileName(filePath2);
            string ext2 = Path.GetExtension(filename2);

            string filePath3 = FileUpload3.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename3 = Path.GetFileName(filePath3);
            string ext3 = Path.GetExtension(filename3);

            string filePath4 = FileUpload4.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename4 = Path.GetFileName(filePath4);
            string ext4 = Path.GetExtension(filename4);

            string filePath5 = FileUpload5.PostedFile.FileName;
            string filename5 = Path.GetFileName(filePath5);
            string ext5 = Path.GetExtension(filename5);

            string contenttype = String.Empty;
            string contenttype2 = String.Empty;
            string contenttype3 = String.Empty;
            string contenttype4 = String.Empty;
            string contenttype5 = String.Empty;

            //Set the contenttype based on File Extension
            switch (ext)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    contenttype = "image/jpg";
                    break;
            }
            switch (ext2)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    contenttype2 = "image/jpg";
                    break;
            }
            switch (ext3)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    contenttype3 = "image/jpg";
                    break;
            }
            switch (ext4)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    contenttype4 = "image/jpg";
                    break;
            }
            switch (ext5)
            {
                case ".jpg":
                    contenttype5 = "image/jpg";
                    break;
            }

                //insert the file into database
                string strQuery = "insert into MemberReport(username, typeofcrime, location, crdatetime, citizenreport)" +
                   " values ('" + username + "','" + typeofcrime + "','" + location.Trim() + "','" + datetime + "','" + detail.Trim() + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
                InsertUpdateData(cmd);

                using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security= SSPI"))
                {
                    connAdd.Open();
                    var sql = "Select memberreportid From MemberReport Where crdatetime = '" + datetime + "'";
                    using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader dr;
                        dr = cmdAdd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (dr.Read())
                        {
                            Session["memberreportid"] = dr["memberreportid"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    connAdd.Close();

                    connAdd.Open();
                    sql = "insert into AdminAssign(memberreportid) values ('" + Session["memberreportid"] + "')";
                    using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
                    {
                        cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    connAdd.Close();
                }

                if(contenttype.Equals("image/jpg"))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image uploaded = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

                    System.Drawing.Image newImage = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                    {
                        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        g.DrawImage(uploaded, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
                    }

                    byte[] results;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                        EncoderParameters jpegParms = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        jpegParms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 95L);
                        newImage.Save(ms, codec, jpegParms);
                        results = ms.ToArray();
                    }

                    string sqlImage = "update MemberReport set image1 = @Data where memberreportid = '" + Session["memberreportid"] + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmdImage = new SqlCommand(sqlImage);
                    cmdImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", results);
                    InsertUpdateData(cmdImage);
                }

                if (contenttype2.Equals("image/jpg"))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image uploaded2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload2.PostedFile.InputStream);

                    System.Drawing.Image newImage2 = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage2))
                    {
                        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        g.DrawImage(uploaded2, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
                    }

                    byte[] results2;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                        EncoderParameters jpegParms = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        jpegParms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 95L);
                        newImage2.Save(ms, codec, jpegParms);
                        results2 = ms.ToArray();
                    }

                    string sqlImage2 = "update MemberReport set image2 = @Data2 where memberreportid = '" + Session["memberreportid"] + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmdImage2 = new SqlCommand(sqlImage2);
                    cmdImage2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data2", results2);
                    InsertUpdateData(cmdImage2);
                }

                if (contenttype3.Equals("image/jpg"))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image uploaded3 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload3.PostedFile.InputStream);

                    System.Drawing.Image newImage3 = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage3))
                    {
                        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        g.DrawImage(uploaded3, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
                    }

                    byte[] results3;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                        EncoderParameters jpegParms = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        jpegParms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 95L);
                        newImage3.Save(ms, codec, jpegParms);
                        results3 = ms.ToArray();
                    }

                    string sqlImage3 = "update MemberReport set image3 = @Data3 where memberreportid = '" + Session["memberreportid"] + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmdImage3 = new SqlCommand(sqlImage3);
                    cmdImage3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data3", results3);
                    InsertUpdateData(cmdImage3);
                }

                if (contenttype4.Equals("image/jpg"))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image uploaded4 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload4.PostedFile.InputStream);

                    System.Drawing.Image newImage4 = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage4))
                    {
                        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        g.DrawImage(uploaded4, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
                    }

                    byte[] results4;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                        EncoderParameters jpegParms = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        jpegParms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 95L);
                        newImage4.Save(ms, codec, jpegParms);
                        results4 = ms.ToArray();
                    }

                    string sqlImage4 = "update MemberReport set image4 = @Data4 where memberreportid = '" + Session["memberreportid"] + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmdImage4 = new SqlCommand(sqlImage4);
                    cmdImage4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data4", results4);
                    InsertUpdateData(cmdImage4);
                }

                if (contenttype5.Equals("image/jpg"))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image uploaded5 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload5.PostedFile.InputStream);

                    System.Drawing.Image newImage5 = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage5))
                    {
                        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        g.DrawImage(uploaded5, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
                    }

                    byte[] results5;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                        EncoderParameters jpegParms = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        jpegParms.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 95L);
                        newImage5.Save(ms, codec, jpegParms);
                        results5 = ms.ToArray();
                    }

                    string sqlImage5 = "update MemberReport set image5 = @Data5 where memberreportid = '" + Session["memberreportid"] + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmdImage5 = new SqlCommand(sqlImage5);
                    cmdImage5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data5", results5);
                    InsertUpdateData(cmdImage5);
                }

            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblMessage.Text = "Report Sent!";

            txtDetail.Text = "";
            txtLocation.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues in your regex.

1. Instead of doing `jpg|JPG`, which wouldn't match jpG, you should simply use case insensitive mode. Or, if all else fails, `(j|J)(p|P)(g|G)`
2. By default, `.` in regex is a wildcard for any character. So even a file ending in `tjpg` would be accepted. You want to escape that . with a backslash.
3. That looks like a nasty regex just to validate a filename. A better thing to do is something like this: `^[^x]+\.jpg$` where x is an invalid path character. Or, if you want to go totally bare bones, something like `^\.jpg$` will ensure that only files with a jpg ext are allowed. (Again here: watch the case insensitivity.)

And several issues with the app itself:

1. String comparison is case sensitive. So in your switch statements, an ext of "JPG" will not match any case (I assume you'll eventually provide support for more file types, otherwise a switch makes no sense there and should be replaced with an if). You should convert the ext to all lower case first before testing it.
2. There's no actual validation of the content type. I could save a GIF, *or a virus*, with a .jpg ext and your system would happily take and store it.
3. Same thing as 2 but with file size.
4. You're building SQL queries with string concat. **This is a big no-no.** It could (read: will) lead to your site being gutted with an SQL injection hack. Use prepared statements *for everything*.

The regex should solve your problem, but consider the other issues I have pointed out.

Comment: Also the (\\(\w[\w].*)) part of your regex is blocking out single-character filenames like "a.jpg".  It would work better as (\\(\w.*)).  The regex as it is requires at least 3 characters before "jpg", but those characters can be anything, for instance "aaajpg".

Comment: @Egg I would just recommend he ditch that regex (which looks like he C/Ped form somewhere) and write a good one that fits his needs. I keep seeing more and more issues with the regex the more I look at it.